# Transform an array into a single value inside a dictionary using Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have this dictionary in python:

```
example = {
    "foo": ["1"],
    "bar": ["1","2"]
}
```

How can i transform efficiently and using Python the variable example to:

```
example = {
    "foo": "1",
    "bar": ["1","2"]
}
```

?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? You can handle this when reading the dict.

Comment: I read the data from a url and I get a dictionary with that format. I need to transform such dictionary into JSON and see if other JSON field in postgres have included that data. *I am using django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the dict is not nesting, you can iterate over the dict to modify it: (Python 3, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python) for difference)

```
for key, value in example.items():
  if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) == 1:
    example[key] = value[0]
```

Comment: This is not slow, but as this is Python it's not as fast as C.

Comment: I was asking just in case there where a more efficient method, for example, a module already built in C

Comment: No, you probably need to make it by hand, if you like a C extension.